# Using like with multiple strings from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

How to write a query to handle substring?

It is easy to do with in as long as the entire string need to be matched. However, how do we handle the same with partial strings?

```
select *
from dbo.mastertable
where string in ( select string from dbo.slave )
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` for a partial string match.  I'm not sure what the exactly logic this, but the idea is:

```
select *
from dbo.mastertable m
where exists (select 1
              from dbo.slave s
              where s.string like '%' + m.string + '%'
             );
```

This means that the `slave.string` contains `master.string`.

Comment: The idea is a sub-query trying to match rows in the two tables for each row in the mastertable. If any match is found the value from the master-table is included. That's why it's not important what the return value is (just number 1 in this case).